# CakePHP database naming convention?

Tags: database, cakephp, naming, conventions

I have two tables:
    doctypes_visas
    users_visas

Now I need I third one that joins the two above.

According to CakePHP naming conventions, what will be the suitable name for this table doctypes_visas_users_visas?

Thanks.

Comment: Try it and find out ;) I believe you've got it right though

Answer (score 3):

As per the [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM), if the association is a `hasAndBelongsToMany` type relationship, you are correct. The name's name should indeed by `doctypes_visas_users_visas`.

**From the documentation:**

> This new join table's name needs to
>   include the names of both models
>   involved, in alphabetical order, and
>   separated with an underscore ( _ ).
>   The contents of the table should be
>   two fields, each foreign keys (which
>   should be integers) pointing to both
>   of the primary keys of the involved
>   models. To avoid any issues - don't
>   define a combined primary key for
>   these two fields, if your application
>   requires it you can define a unique
>   index.